# How to manage Kafka producer and consumer when the producer is on the private network of the Kafka server and the consumer is on the public network?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

The system on which my Kafka server is running has a public IP `12.24.125.117` that is accessible by the system on which the consumer runs.

The private IP of the Kafka server is `123.123.123.105` and is accessible by the system on which the producer runs.

If I set the listeners property in server.properties to use `123.123.123.105` the producer is able to produce the messages successfully. But the consumer cannot consume. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: if you are not setting listeners explicity, kafka by default will bind to all the interfaces.. do `netstat -lntp | grep 9092` and confirm it...

Comment: You really have two interfaces or this is a cloud instance like AWS with an elastic IP?

Comment: It is just a simple server with two network cards, one accessible by the producer and one by the consumer. Thanks a lot for all your support. By not setting the listeners explicitly, the system worked. Apart from that I provided the advertised.host.name property and made a DNS Lookup Host file entry on the client side mapping the name to the public IP of the server. This worked for me.